# Get the last accessed time a client sends a request using the same session in jsf?

Tags: jsf, session, httpsession

I am currently using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
```

,is there any way i can get the last accessed time a client makes request associated with the same session, just like

```
Session.getLastAccessedTime()
```

? As of now, i could find any methods. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve the current HttpSession from the [external context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html):

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext
    .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.getSession(false);
```

Then get the [last accessed time](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime%28%29):

```
if (session != null)
    long ms = session.getLastAccesedTime();
else
    System.out.println("There's no session created for the current user");
```

You may convert it into a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) later on:

```
Date d = new Date(ms);
```

Comment: @Xtreme I believe one should not create a new session under the mentioned requirements. So I'd rather call `ec.getSession(false)` and use a `null` check afterwards. If there's no current session, just set time to some negative predefined value.